# Pattern in while loop

Tags: php

```
<table>
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
<tr>
<td>
echo $row['test'] . " " . ' ($' . $row['test2'] . ")<br>";
</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

How do I make a pattern for the background color? For ex, grey, blue, grey blue.

Comment: Your English doesn't make sense. Colors don't ask you to make patterns for them.

Comment: What would be the proper way to say it?

Comment: @Doug: Suggestion, "How do I make a pattern with an alternating background color?"

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399137/easiest-way-to-alternate-row-colors-in-php-html I'm sure this as been asked and solved on SO many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like a state variable, where you store wheter the last row was blue or grey. Then you print out the other color and update the state variable for the next pass.

This is one example:

```
<?php

echo '<table>';

$state = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    if( $state%2 == 0 )
        echo '<td style="background-color:grey;">';
    else
        echo '<td style="background-color:blue;">';
    echo $row['test'] . " " . ' ($' . $row['test2'] . ")<br>";
    echo '</td></tr>';
    $state++;
}
echo '</table>';

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this. Here is one.

```
<table>
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
<tr<?php echo (++$i & 1 == 1) ? ' class="odd"' : '' ?>>
<td>
<?php echo $row['test'] . " " . ' ($' . $row['test2'] . ") ?><br>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

I suggest giving a CSS class (I've called it "odd" here) to every second row rather than both odd and even. Then you just do:

```
tr td { background: grey; }
tr.odd td { background: blue; }
```

in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a 2 colour pattern, use a variable to switch between blue and grey. if more than 2 colours, use a rotating counter

2 colours

```
$blue = true;
<table>
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
<tr>
<td color="<?php echo $blue?'blue':'grey'; $blue ^= true; ?>">
echo $row['test'] . " " . ' ($' . $row['test2'] . ")<br>";
</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

More than 2 colours, the general solution:

```
$colourIndex = 0;
$colours = ('blue', 'red', 'green');

...
...

<td color="<?php echo $colours[$colourIndex]; $colourIndex = ($colourIndex+1)%length($colours); ?>">
```

Comment: `$blue = !$blue` is a less _clever_ method.

Comment: ($counter + 1)%n where n is the number of colours you have :P

Comment: haha Ollie, I used xor because in my experience, it's normally used to flip a bit, while $blue = !$blue looks a bit confusing...even philosophical, "blue is not blue", "2b|!2b", "i.think() => i.am()"

Comment: Clarification: It's a "rotating counter" because it "rotates" back to start after it counts to the last number of an interval (interval being a sequence of numbers with a start and an end number).

Comment: @Charles Ma: I usually tell early programming students that "=" is not an equals sign. Instead it is "this is assigned with this" in order to clear up any confusion between the semantics of "=" and "==" in C-like languages.

Comment: @Charles It's not philosophical because it's not a statement of truth, like it would be in a functional language, it's a sequence of operations: 1) get $blue, 2) invert truth of got value, 3) assign new value to $blue.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My point was that it feels more natural to me to use xor rather than ! in that particular situation because of my previous experiences :P

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [InfiniteIterator](http://docs.php.net/class.infiniteiterator) to repeat the sequence again and again. This, like the "rotating counter", works for an arbitrary amount of elements.

```
$props = new InfiniteIterator(
  new ArrayIterator(array('a', 'b', 'c','d', 'e'))
); $props->rewind();

$l = rand(10, 20); // or whatever
for ($i=0; $i<$l; $i++) {
  $p = $props->current(); $props->next();
  echo 'class="', $p, '"... ';
}
```

Comment: Really? I find this solution easier to read than the others. And easier to tweak.