# How to give alternating table rows different background colors using PHP

Tags: php

I have a table of data that is generated dynamically based on the contents stored in a mysql database.

This is how my code looks:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $catName = $row['name'];
            $catDes = $row['description'];
            $catUrl = $row['url'];

            echo "<tr class=''>";
            echo "<td>$catName</td>";
            echo "<td>$catDes</td>";
            echo "<td>$catUrl</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Now if the table was static, then I would just assign each alternating table row one of 2 styles in repeated order:

```
.whiteBackground { background-color: #fff; }
.grayBackground { background-color: #ccc; }
```

and that would be the end of that. However since the table rows are dynamically generated, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Look into the modulus operator =)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<?php 

$x++; 

$class = ($x%2 == 0)? 'whiteBackground': 'grayBackground';

echo "<tr class='$class'>";

?>
```

It basically checks to see if $x is divisible evenly by 2. If it is, it is even.

P.S. if you haven't seen that style of if else query, it is called a ternary operator.

Comment: The dot shouldn't be in the classname if it's going straight into html ;)

Comment: without using css of course you can simply substitute the location of the class variable for bgcolour ie `$class = ($x%2 == 0)? 'white': 'gray';` `echo "<tr bgcolor='$class'>";`

Comment: `bgcolor` is supported for legacy websites, but you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Note that "background" is capitalized in the OP's code: `grayBackground `.

Answer (score 22):

Or you could just use CSS:

`table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ccc;
}`

Comment: How could you modify this to not include the top row?

Comment: I got that, but what if I want the odd rows one color, and the even rows one color, but also the top row to top have the coloring? Is that possible?

Comment: Then you would create a style for table tr:first-child { background-color: #foo; }

Answer (score 2):

Set a variable to true/false or a number and then back again during each iteration. Or use the modulus operator such as $i%2==0 in a while loop where $i is a number and use this condition in a ternary statement or something that sets the class value of the `<tr>`

[Easiest way to alternate row colors in PHP/HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399137/easiest-way-to-alternate-row-colors-in-php-html)

```
$i = 0;
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
 echo '<tr class="' . ( ( $i %2 == 0 ) ? 'oneValue' : 'anotherValue' ) . '"><td>' . $row['something'] . '</td></tr>';
$i++;
}
```

Comment: This is not a *reverse* while loop. ;)

Comment: No it isn't - I just stated that. Better change my statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
$color="1";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if($color==1){
    echo '<tr bgcolor="">';
    $color="2";
  } else { 
    echo '<tr bgcolor="#dcdcdc">';
    $color="1";
  }
  ?><td align="left" width="40"><a href=""></a><?= $line[name] ?></td>

<?
}
?>
```

This is my working code !

Comment: Instead of using a string value for `$color` you can also (better) use a boolean: `$color = true` (you'd need to modify the rest of your example as well)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working part !
`

```
 $i=1;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 if($i%2==0)
 {
     echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFF00">';
 }
 else
 {
     echo '<tr bgcolor="#99FFCC">';
 }
     $i++;
     echo "<td>" . $row['blah'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['blah_blah'] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";

 }
 echo "</table>";
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. I declared a css class called "even" with all the styling i wanted. Then looped through the scenario. Hope it helps!

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    echo "<table id='hor-zebra'>";
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       if($i%2 == 0)
       {
          echo "<tr class='even'>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['something'] ." ". $row['something'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
       }

       else
       {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['something'] ." ". $row['something'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
       }
       $i++;
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysql_close($con);

  ?>
```