# How can I generate different color lines for each row added on a table generated from SQL?

Tags: php, html, sql, whmcs

As it is the code generates every line the same color, how can I make it so that it will add a slightly darker shade every other line?

i.e.:
white
beige
white
beige
white
beige

So that it becomes a more readable format.

Code below:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $invoiceitemssql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tblinvoiceitems WHERE invoiceid = '.$row['id'].' LIMIT 0,1');
        $invoiceitems = mysql_fetch_array($invoiceitemssql);
        $html .= '<tr>
            <td><a href="invoices.php?action=edit&id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'</a></td>
            <td>'.$row['firstname'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['lastname'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['companyname'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['city'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['phonenumber'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['duedate'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['total'].'</td>
            <td>'.$invoiceitems['description'].'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a [fairly common and frequently asked question here](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+alternating+color+while+mysql).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to give alternating table rows different background colors using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034511/how-to-give-alternating-table-rows-different-background-colors-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so

```
$i = 0;

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        color white
    } else {
        color beige
    }

    $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy to understand, I'm not much of a coder, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter to switch the background color:

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     if($i%2 == 0)
         $bgcolor='beige'; // change the color code as needed
     else 
         $bgcolor='white';
     $i++;
     ......
     $html .= '<tr style="background:#'.$bcolor.'">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS [nth-child selector](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html) for this, it makes it so you do not have to do messy php loops to add coloring.

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background:#F00;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background:#FF0;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xmYXY/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to style each different rows..

for example:

```
tr:nth-child(odd)
{
   background:#fff;
}
tr:nth-child(even)
{
   background:#ddd;
}
```