# Alter class on every 1/5 entry with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Using PHP to generate out a list.

I Simply want to set a different class on every fifth entry. (1/5), (4+1)

```
<li class="<?php the_code();?>"> content </li>
```

Output would be like this

```
<li class="yolo"> Content </li>
<li class="yolo"> Content </li>
<li class="yolo"> Content </li>
<li class="yolo"> Content </li>
<li class="hello"> Content </li>
<li class="yolo"> Content </li>
<li class="yolo"> Content </li>
<li class="yolo"> Content </li>
<li class="yolo"> Content </li>
<li class="hello"> Content </li>
```

How can i do this ?

Guess it's pure basic for anyone with php skills, that's not me but i would also be glad to get pointed towards some page that explains this so i can learn it.

To clarify am using Wordpress loop and it contains +100 items and i want to alter class on item 5,10,15,20,25,30,35 etc..

Comment: PHP's [modulus operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (`%`) may be useful here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to alternate row colors in PHP/HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399137/easiest-way-to-alternate-row-colors-in-php-html)

Comment: Is the list hard-coded, or are you using a php loop to create the list?

Comment: php loop, it's within Wordpress

Comment: What WP function are you using to generate the list?

Comment: <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a counter (`$i`) and increment it on each time you create a new list item (`++$i`), then check to see if the result is divisible by 5 (`% 5 == 0`). Then simply use the ternary operator (`?…:…`) to decide which value to output:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>

<?php for(...) { ?>
  <li class="<?= (++$i) % 5 == 0 ? 'yolo' : 'hello' ?>"> content </li>
<?php } ?>
```

But it truth, there's no need to even use PHP, when a little CSS will probably do the job:

```
li:nth-child(5n)
{
    ...
}
```

See a demonstation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9pMhN/).

Comment: Note to OP, the `:nth-child` pseudo class selector will not function properly in IE8 or lower. I would still recommend the CSS approach, though. Also, if you are setting a class for interaction with vanilla JavaScript DOM selection, you'll want to stick with the PHP solution.

Comment: Did test css approach but here it would only do it on the first occurrence of the 1/5 item. The rest of the list did keep it's original class. Guess it's because am using it within a Loop or because of using masonry.js / Lazyload.js / Imagesloaded.js

Comment: I wan't to change class on every fifth item. The list is +100 items but every fifth. Item 5,10,15,20,25,30,35 etc

Comment: Using `<?= (++$i) == 5 ? 'yolo' : 'hello' ?>` gives me "hello" on every class

Comment: @MathiasÅsberg Sorry, I misunderstood your earlier comment. Yes, my mistake. `li:nth-child(5)` only modifies *the* 5th child,  `li:nth-child(5n)` modifies *every* 5th child. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As a drop in function for the code you provided:

```
function the_code() {
    static $count = 0;
    $count++;
    echo $count % 5 == 0 ? 'hello':'yolo';
}
```

the static keyword in the function keeps the value of count whenever the function is called.