# PHP shorthand variable toggle for table row background colors

Tags: php, html, css, toggle

I've been using the following shorthand in php lately for defining table row background colors.

**Are there are caveats to using this method**, other than perhaps obscurity?

```
 <?php $style = 'style="background-color:#CCC;"'; ?>
 <tr <?php if ($i = !$i) echo $style; ?>>
      <td><input /></td>
 <tr>
```

What's happening is `$i = !$i` means $i cannot equal $i, so if $i is true the first time, it becomes false, and vice versa. The `if` of course checks the value `true or false` each time, thereby outputting the style every other time and obtaining the every-other background effect.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399137/easiest-way-to-alternate-row-colors-in-php-html

Comment: The caveat of obscurity should be motivation enough to consider another option, as side effects and assignments in conditions are generally frowned upon.

Comment: @BenLee thanks for the link, not sure how I didn't find that before, but I guess the questions are still different (easiest way vs. caveats to using this way)

Comment: Outside the aspect of obscurity, I'm wondering if this method has any performance advantages/disadvantages or potential to manifest a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get your logic of $i != $i, but still if i understood that you want different colors for alternating TR , it can be done at css level. Use CSS - nth Property.

try :

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: red;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: blue;
}
```

OR

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
     background: yellow;
}
```

Note: **Use 2n+0** or **2n+1** for alternate - starting first row + 2, or 2nd row + 2

Comment: Good alternative if not using php, but the $i = !$i toggle could be useful in applications outside CSS... simply as any toggle. Basically in php the expression is a BOOLEAN. So, it must be `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If it's first `TRUE`, then it becomes `FALSE` as it cannot be the current state.