# Assign different class names to div with php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have four divs in one page which are styled so that it has four alternating colours. And the even div i.e. 2nd and 4th have an extra class name 'r' like this.

```
<div class="x-1 liner"><div>
<div class="x-2 liner r"><div>
<div class="x-3 liner"><div>
<div class="x-4 liner r"><div>
```

The results are pulled from the database, I can use the modulus operator (`%`) to assign alternating colours for two rows as shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399137/easiest-way-to-alternate-row-colors-in-php-html) but how can I do this for four rows and also add 'r' to the even divs?

Comment: Use %2 for the r values and %4 for the colours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [kojow7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4698242/kojow7) says you can use `% 2` and `% 4`, see this code:

```
<?php

for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
  echo "div class='x-$i liner";
  if($i % 2 == 0) echo ' r';
  if($i % 4 == 0) echo ' color';
  echo "'><div>\n"; 
}   

?>
```

Output:

```
div class='x-1 liner'><div>
div class='x-2 liner r'><div>
div class='x-3 liner'><div>
div class='x-4 liner r color'><div>
```

EDIT:
With a `foreach` should be like this, but I don't know what values have `$data`

```
<?php

$i = 1;

foreach($data as $row) {
  echo "div class='x-$i liner";
  if($i % 2 == 0) echo ' r';
  if($i % 4 == 0) echo ' color';
  echo "'><div>\n"; 
  $i++;
}   

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, how can use this inside a foreach loop like this: foreach($data as $row) { } if I place it inside I get the results four times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AbuNooh I edit my answer, but I don't know the values in your $data var

Comment: That's it done, big thanks. Also found I could just increment a number without the loop but this is perfect.

Comment: @AbuNooh you're welcome and god luck in your work ;-)